# VS Code is not including .js after doing an auto import

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

When working with NodeJS in VS Code, I've had issues where the auto-import function of VS Code wouldn't include the `.js` extension as required by the Node module system.

**For example:**

```js
// As required by Node
import { foo } from './foo.js'

// As added by VS Code
import { foo } from './foo'
```

When left as specified by VS Code, I get the following error:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:91
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '\mbot\util\strings' imported from \mbot\index.js
Did you mean to import ../util/strings.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:405:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:966:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1176:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:318:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved by adding a `jsconfig.json` file to your project root. Specifically by including at least the following, my project started auto-importing with the `.js` file extension as required by NodeJS.

**`jsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext", // <- Necessary to get imports with .js
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Note:**
VS Code will complain about the `nodenext` value requiring a special package, but it works fine without it.